# How can i get value of an object in a list of KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, keyvaluepair

`var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IObject>>(){};`

I want to `Console.WriteLine()` the actual value of interface **IObject** from the list. How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try already? There are hundreds of questions about getting a string-representation of some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to print. If IObject returns it's value in for example Info() method then it should look something like this.

```
foreach (var kvp in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value.Info());
}
```

Comment: `Info`-method? How do you come to the conclusion there may exist something like that? Wouldn´t a `ToString` me a more viable assumption?

Comment: IObject is an interface then I assume that it is implementing some methods which return it's "value".

Comment: I think we are getting there and this will help. Is there a a way to access a **single** value of IObject without looping over?

Comment: Of course, you need to specify the index of the list. For example, if you want to access the first element of list the code will look like this:

list[0].Value.Info();

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list items and print its values:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Comment: This **may** solve OPs problem, if `IObject` also imlements some `ToString`, which I guess is OPs **actual** problem - just a guess.

Comment: `object` type implements `ToString`, so it will print something ;-)

Comment: Sure it will. But if that something makes sense is another question. Most probably OP gets something like `MyNamespace.MyObject`.

Comment: Indeed, string is just one of the type in the cases I am targeting for the interface object type.